# Using TypeScript's InstanceType generics with abstract classes?

Tags: typescript, generics, casting

TypeScript 2.8 added a new core type `InstanceType` which can be used to get the return type of a constructor function.

```
/**
 * Obtain the return type of a constructor function type
 */
type InstanceType<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends new (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : any;
```

This feature is pretty nice, but falls apart when using abstract classes, which don't have a `new` declaration according to TypeScript's type system.

At first, I thought I could get around this limitation by creating a similar but less-restrictive type (removing the `extends new (...args: any[]) => any` guard):

```
export type InstanceofType<T> = T extends new(...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : any;
```

But it too falls apart when passed an abstract class, as it cannot infer the return type and defaults to `any`. Here's an example using a mock DOM as an example, with attempted type casting.

```
abstract class DOMNode extends Object {
    public static readonly TYPE: string;
    constructor() { super(); }
    public get type() {
        return (this.constructor as typeof DOMNode).TYPE;
    }
}

class DOMText extends DOMNode {
    public static readonly TYPE = 'text';
    constructor() { super(); }
}

abstract class DOMElement extends DOMNode {
    public static readonly TYPE = 'text';
    public static readonly TAGNAME: string;
    constructor() { super(); }
    public get tagname() {
        return (this.constructor as typeof DOMElement).TAGNAME;
    }
}

class DOMElementDiv extends DOMElement {
    public static readonly TAGNAME = 'div';
    constructor() { super(); }
}

class DOMElementCanvas extends DOMElement {
    public static readonly TAGNAME = 'canvas';
    constructor() { super(); }
}

// Create a collection, which also discards specific types.
const nodes = [
    new DOMElementCanvas(),
    new DOMText(),
    new DOMElementDiv(),
    new DOMText()
];

function castNode<C extends typeof DOMNode>(instance: DOMNode, Constructor: C): InstanceofType<C> | null {
    if (instance.type !== Constructor.TYPE) {
        return null;
    }
    return instance as InstanceofType<C>;
}

// Attempt to cast the first one to an element or null.
// This gets a type of any:
const element = castNode(nodes[0], DOMElement);
console.log(element);
```

Is there any way I can cast a variable to being an instance of the constructor that is passed, if that constructor is an abstract class?

NOTE: I'm trying to avoid using `instanceof` because JavaScript's `instaceof` is very problematic (2 different versions of the same module have different constructor instances).

Comment: Can you provide a use case? It seems to me that the type system is being pretty smart about this. It's structural so I can't see any use for it but I'm curious what yours is

Comment: @AluanHaddad Mainly I have a collection objects that share a common parent type, but are each a different sub type (think XML or DOM nodes), that I need to be able to cast to their original types to use their unique methods (ie. a `canvas` DOM node would have a `getContext` method, but other nodes would not).

Comment: If the methods are instance methods, you can use an `instanceof` check or an `in` check or one of numerous other options. I have a suspicion that you are using excessive type annotations, since that usually is what leads to one thinking they need such functionality, but I would need to see actual use

Comment: @AluanHaddad JavaScript's `instanceof` is problematic (2 different versions of the same JS module would have different constructor objects), so I don't want to use that. What do you mean by an `in` check?

Comment: I completely agree with you that `instanceof` is abominable, and your reason for avoiding it is very strong. `in` just checks to see if an object contains a property key anywhere in its prototype chain and it acts as a type guard. By the way, if the air goes away when the class isn't abstract then it's not worth making the class abstract as it provides very few benefits if any

Comment: At ain't rate, it seems to me that you could solve the problem by changing the type of second argument to the casting function to `Constructor: (new (... args: any[]) => Derived) & {TYPE: string}` where `Derived`  is a type parameter

Comment: @AluanHaddad That doesn't seem to work. I think the issue is in the return type.

Comment: Just use [this function](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20castNode%3CD%20extends%20DOMNode%2C%20DE%20extends%20typeof%20DOMNode%3E(instance%3A%20DOMNode%2C%20Constructor%3A%20DE)%3A%20DE%5B'prototype'%5D%20%7C%20null%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(instance.type%20!%3D%3D%20Constructor.TYPE)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20instance%20as%20DE%5B'prototype'%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D). It is actually a lot simpler than it sounds. What makes you situation tricky was 2 levels of abstract classes.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Hey! That seems to do the trick! Care to post an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query type of the `prototype` of an abstract `class` to obtain the type of its instances. This does not require that the type have a `new` signature only that it has a `prototype` property. Abstract classes do not have a `new` signature but they do have a `prototype` property.

Here is what it looks like

```
function castNode<C extends typeof DOMNode>(
  instance: DOMNode,
  Constructor: C
): C['prototype'] | null {
  if (instance.type !== Constructor.TYPE) {
    return null;
  }
  return instance;
}
```

The expression `C['P']` in type position is called an indexed access type. It is the type of the *value* of the property named `P` in the *type* `C`.